# How to use blocking (I/O bound) APIs within Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, threadpool, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm writing a Kotlin server using [Ktor](http://ktor.io/) - where my request handlers are written using Kotlin coroutines.

My understanding is each request handler is run on Ktor's thread pool, which contains *far fewer threads* than the traditional pool size of 1-thread-per-request server frameworks due to the lightweight/suspendable nature of coroutines. Great!

The issue I have is that my application still needs to interact with some **blocking** resources (JDBC database connection pool), but my understanding is that if I merely call these blocking APIs directly from the request coroutine I will end up with **liveness issues** - as I can end up blocking all the threads used to handle my requests! Not great.

Since I'm still relatively new to the world of Kotlin and coroutines, I'm wondering if anyone here can give me some tips on the best way to handle this situation.

---

I've seen [`Dispatchers.IO`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html) referenced a few times elsewhere. Is that considered the best way to manage these blocking calls? Are there any good examples of this?

The API I'm trying to use does allow for some asyncronicity by passing an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). Ideally, I could also wrap these calls in a convenient, idiomatic Kotlin API for `suspend`ing transactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You understand it all correctly. In most cases you should never block the thread when inside a coroutine. One exception is `Dispatchers.IO` mentioned by you. It is the standard way of handling blocking code and it is very easy to use:

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // blocking code
}
```

`withContext()` is a suspend function, so you can think of above as the way to convert blocking to suspend. However, `Dispatchers.IO` doesn't really perform any magic - it just uses a bigger pool of threads, designated for blocking. I believe by default it creates 64 threads at maximum.

If you need to perform several parallel blocking operations, it is usually better to create your own thread pool to not block other components of the application.

If the IO library provides asynchronous API then generally it is better to use it instead of the blocking API. However, in many cases libraries provide asynchronous API by managing their own internal thread pool for blocking. In that case using asynchronous API and using blocking API with `Dispatchers.IO` is very similar. `Dispatchers.IO` could be even better, because it re-uses same IO threads across all IO operations and it can partially share threads with a thread pool designated for CPU computations (`Dispatchers.Default`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that is helpful. So probably I can make a helper function - which I call everywhere I call DB code - that just wraps a `Unit` function with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` and maybe a DB transaction as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. the Dispatchers.IO would be the answer. I had a test with quarkus. The vert.x had no 2-seconds-blocking-alarm after I switched JDBC connection to Dispatchers.IO

https://github.com/hmchangm/quarkus-reactive-kotlin/blob/mariadb/src/main/kotlin/tw/idv/brandy/arrow/repo/FruitRepo.kt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).